# How to open a source file in GDB TUI

Tags: gdb

When I'm GDB TUI can I load arbitrary source file for browsing without jumping into it using breakpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't list any arbitrary file, but if it's part of your program, you can try something like

```
list sourcefile.c:1
```

That :1 at the end says to list from line number 1, and lets gdb know that it's file, not a function.

Comment: nice, I didn't add the line number and thought the command does not work in TUI mode.